# Centering text in a button but having a left aligned visual icon for that same button?

Tags: html, css

I have a need to design a button that looks like this:

[image]

Here is what I currently have:

[image]

The two things I cannot solve:

1. How do I align just that dot to the left?
2. How do I center the text while having the dot still there?

```css
.login-button {
    width: 85%;
}

.dot {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #003920;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.center-button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-button">
<button mat-stroked-button color="primary" class="login-button" (click)="loginWithGoogle()">
    <span class="dot"></span> Login with Google</button>
```

Comment: .dot { float: left; }

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `float: left` is what you are looking for?

Also, this will slightly push the text to the right.

You can put your text inside a span and add some right padding equal in size to the width of your circle, which will center it.

```html
<span style="padding-right: 20px;">Login with Google</span>
```

```css
.login-button {
    width: 85%;
}

.dot {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: #003920;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    float: left;
}
.center-button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-button">
<button mat-stroked-button color="primary" class="login-button" (click)="loginWithGoogle()">
    <span class="dot"></span><span style="padding-right: 20px;">Login with Google</span></button>
```

Comment: Pfft... Well, I feel dumb for forgetting that. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. I've been building websites for almost 3 years now and I still forget how to import CSS style sheets lol.

Comment: hoever float will consume space and as such the text is no longer centered within the button.

Comment: Yep, which I covered a solution for in my answer.

Comment: yes but then you need to sue clac which you also said and calculate the rigth value. using position: relative + position: absolute would be easier as the dot is no longer aprt of the normal flow. The way more simple solution.

Comment: Float doesn't work with position absolute. This is the simplest way to do it, but there are certainly more proper ways to do it like using position absolute.

Answer (score 1):

While coding something like this I tend to give the layout decisions to the parent element ( here login btn ) while child elements should just specify their widths and let the parent handle the placing. ( It's just how I like to do it. No hard & fast rule. )

So you can do something like this :

```css
.login-button {
  width: 85%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.dot {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #003920;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.text {
  flex: auto 1 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-button">
  <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" class="login-button" (click)="loginWithGoogle()">
<span class="dot"></span> <span class="text">Login with Google</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: why use `width: calc(100% - 20px)` ? You applied a flexbox to the button. You could simply use `flex-grow: 1` to the text instead of calculatin its width.

Comment: sure...good suggestion !

Answer (score 1):

Give the button a `position: relative` and the dot a `position:absolute`. Also change height and width to 1em to fit the line height.

```css
.login-button {
  width: 85%;
  position: relative;
}

.dot {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background-color: #003920;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}

.center-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-button">
  <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" class="login-button" (click)="loginWithGoogle()">
    <span class="dot"></span> Login with Google</button>
```